# Azure live login works on localhost but not when deployed to Azure

Tags: azure, active-directory

I'm able to login and and get authorized from Azure when running on localhost but when I deploy it to the server I'm getting unauthorized.

The reply urls look correct but when I deploy my core 2.1 MVC website to Azure I'm getting the status back that I'm not Authorized.

Any help would be appreciated.

Phillip

Comment: What do you mean deploying to Azure? Do you deploy your website on Azure VM or Azure web app service?

Comment: You need to elaborate more.  What Language , cloud technology are you using and possibly code part showing how are you trying to Authorize?

Comment: You could share us the authorization you used and how did  you  deploy the site?

Answer (score 1):

If it is working on localhost but not as a published application it is likely that you have a reference to localhost either somewhere in your web.config/app settings or in your app registration. As you mentioned you need to ensure that your reply urls in your code and in your registration are pointing to your published app URL and not localhost. Make sure that the Client ID in your application matches the Application ID in Azure and ensure that the Tenant ID in your code matches the tenant ID where the app is deployed.

Also, make sure you are following the right process for publishing your app to Azure and that Azure AD is not creating a new app for your instance. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/quickstart-deploy-to-azure?view=vs-2017

If all of these settings are correct, try enabling web server logging under Platform Features > Diagnostic Logs and checking the logs for information.

EDIT: I re-read and it is unclear to me whether your unauthorized error occurs upon publication or upon login. If it happens at login make sure that your user is added in the AAD tenant and granted permission to the application.